# How do I connect to a wireless access point?

Tags: 10.10, wireless, lubuntu

I have Lubuntu 10.10 I think... running on an old machine but it runs well. But I can use the terminal to see all my wireless cards but is there an easy way to connect to a wireless access point. Once again answers are very appreciated

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Open 'Desktop Session Settings' from the applications menu then tick the netwrok manager and when you restart you will find the network manager switched on.

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu has the same graphical Network Manager as most other flavors of Ubuntu. The Network Manager icon should appear on your notification area (the right side of the panel).

[image: Network Manager icon] (It appears smaller than this, of course.)

This is what it looks like on my Lubuntu system:

[image]

(I keep my panel at the top--it's more common in Lubuntu to have it at the bottom of the screen, so yours might be there.)

As shown, when you click on it, you get a menu where you can connect and disconnect your wireless interface (as well as any other interfaces, such as Ethernet). For wireless, you can choose which network you wish to join.

This is just the same as in "vanilla" Ubuntu.

### If you don't have that...

...then perhaps the Network Manager is not set to run automatically, for some reason. [Alaukik's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/23975/22949) addresses that.